# Unable to call COM object with elevated privileges

Tags: python, windows, dll, com, pywin32

I am working on a Python script that interacts with a COM object of Autodesk Inventor. I can create this object like so:

```py
>>> import win32com.client
>>> win32com.client.Dispatch('Inventor.Application')
```

When I am running it normally, it works fine. However, when I run it in a shell with admin permissions I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

To try to find the cause of this issue, I followed the steps detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71020409). I created this VB Script,

```
set obj = CreateObject("Inventor.Application")
MsgBox TypeName(obj)
```

And ran it with both 32 and 64 bit engines under varying permissions:

- **User permissions**- Script runs correctly both times
- **Admin permissions**- Script throws error both times

I also checked `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in my registry, and the application is there and spelled correctly. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This depends on how Inventor.Application setups itself. It may not be supported (https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-ilogic-and-vb-net-forum/start-an-inventor-instance-using-api/td-p/4364095). Can you try to start inventor first and call vbscript GetObject("Inventor.Application"), not as admin? Then close all instances of inventor, start it as admin and call call vbscript GetObject("Inventor.Application") as admin